# PHP huge mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select from database about `200 000 rows`, how to do this fast ?

Select by part and in result merge arrays or use cache or something like this ?

Select contain `2 inner join`.

SQL select is fast `5ms`, but how to analyse this data with php (in loop ) fast ?

Comment: If your database design is good (with good indices mainly), this should be relatively fast to fetch. What will be longer will be the data processing in your PHP code. What do you want to do with 200.000 rows of data in a single PHP page ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant I need analyse all record with complex conditions with PHP (I cant this do in SQL) and choose only correct records and display in page. How to do this fast with PHP ?

Comment: There's no way we can help you without seeing some code showing what you're trying to do and why you can't do it in SQL. My guess is that you won't be able to process it fast on PHP side. Looping through 200.000 rows WILL take some time, whatever you do.

Comment: 200,000 is not very much . i did some select with about 800K rows in less than a sec. it depends on your database designing.

Comment: The answer will depend on what you mean by "fast". What sort of run time would be acceptable in your application?

Comment: I run time must be no more than 1s.

Comment: you should use lazy load technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me when you have huge results it is recommended to use batches (performance and memory reasons). You are reading this [Do huge MySQL queries in batches when using PHP](http://www.seancolombo.com/2009/07/05/quick-tip-do-huge-mysql-queries-in-batches-when-using-php/)

Comment: According to OP's edit, the data fetching is not the culprit here.